# Free PDF Editor software for Ubuntu 20.04 is needed

Tags: pdf, editing

I am new user of Ubuntu 20.04. I need free PDF editor software for creating and editing PDF files, and for exporting the pages from the PDF files and the PDF files itself, in another format (docx, e.t.c.). I will appreciate your help.

Comment: as in the link above there is libreoffice here is there site (https://www.libreoffice.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read the tips. There are some useful, which helps. I would like to wait for more answers, to read more tips.

Comment: I just use AbiWord, as my needs are few. However, see [this link](https://itsfoss.com/pdf-editors-linux/). This question is also rather close to being 'opinion-based'.

Comment: Another vote for LibreOffice Draw.